# How do I permanently disable IE script debugging on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

I need to get rid of this:
[image]

I am supposed to disable this check box under "Internet Options">
[image]

However, this option doesn't exist on Windows 10 2004/20H2

Comment: **It has to exist**, since the features of IE11 have not changed in years, I can confirm IE11 on 21H1 does indeed have this options.  Future builds past 21H1 have already remove IE11 in advanced of IE11 being completely unsupported in 2022.  If IE11 on 21H1 has the options then IE11 on 2004 and 20H2 also have it.

Comment: [I was able to confirm that on IE11 on Windows 10 version 20H2 the option you are looking for does indeed exist.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsi9w.png)

Comment: @Ramhound alright, thanks. It turns out that IE11 was disabled. This is a fresh install, but I guess that due to Windows' account synchronization it pulled this setting from my previous install.

Comment: Windows Features are not synchronized between your profile, if IE11 was disabled entirely, then it was purposefully disabled by someone

Comment: @Ramhound whatever you say, I had just installed windows on the very same day, and IE11 was disabled‍♂️, and no, no one disabled it because I live alone.

But anyways, that doesn't matter now, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this option was not showing up for me due to Internet Explorer 11 being disabled under **Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off**
[image]

After enabling it and restarting, the missing checkbox showed up under internet options, and upon unchecking it the problem with the scripts went away (actually, for one of the programs where the script dialog showed up, the very fact IE11 was enabled fixed the issue): [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the option on Windows 10 21H1.

[image]

Try resetting IE to default values and then restart your computer and check.

Comment: Worth pointing out that Internet Properties has existed within Control Panel since Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I found out my issue was that IE11 was disabled, so I enabled it again and the checkbox showed up.